# Buffer overread

Tags: buffer-overflow, memory, c

I am trying to understand buffer overread in my course in school. This code is an example from one of the lectures where buffer overread can be a problem. However, I do not understand how buffer overread can occur in this code.

In my knowledge, `b` is assigned char of length 4 (0 to 3) but the string is only of length 3 (0 to 2). The last char is then assigned after. `b[3] = "d";`. How is that buffer overread? It is setting the char `"d"` to the last allocated element in the array. For me, buffer overread is if someone tried to read `b[5]`, which is not in the boundaries of the array, but `b[3]` is.

Can someone please explain?

```
int main()
{
    char b[4] = "abc";
    b[3] = "d";
    printf("b: %s \n", b);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings in C are null-terminated, so it should end on `\0`. When `b[3]` was changed, you removed the `\0` and now the string is unbounded. Running it will let `printf` read everything until it gets the first `\0`, terminating the string.

Why this is an issue? It will print memory that it wasn't supposed to print. That's the issue that caused Heartbleed: you were able to read more data than you were supposed to read.